# LINQ Join Order By then Result Order By

Tags: c#, linq, join, sql-order-by

I have a LINQ to construct a list of buildings, which has a field consisting of a list of Users:

```
List<Building> buildings = (from b in db.Buildings
    join u in db.BuildingUsers on b.BuildingId equals u.BuildingId into bUsers
    orderby b.BuildDate descending
    select Building.Create(b, bUsers)).ToList();
```

The UserName is not always the user I want.  What I really want is the first User that was ever entered, which I think is correct to assume it would be the BuildingUser with the lowest UserID.  So I do the Order By:

```
List<Building> buildings = (from b in db.Buildings
    join u in db.BuildingUsers on b.BuildingId equals u.BuildingId into bUsers
    orderby u.UserId ascending
    select Building.Create(b, bUsers)).ToList();
```

That works great, except now my overall list of buildings is in an awkward order.  The bUsers is passed into the Create method in the correct order, and I handle the FirstOrDefault() to get the first user and handle the rest.  I want the end-result of the overall building list to be in order by BuildDate.

```
List<Building> buildings = (from b in db.Buildings
    join u in db.BuildingUsers on b.BuildingId equals u.BuildingId into bUsers
    orderby u.UserId ascending, b.BuildDate descending
    select Building.Create(b, bUsers)).ToList();
```

Of course this doesn't work, because now it first sorts by UserId, then by BuildDate and doesn't quite turn out correctly.

So I want one orderby for the Join, and a different orderby for the main result.  I'd rather not split them into multiple methods so I don't have to alter the way I construct my building objects.

Comment: Could you try doing `buildings.OrderByDescending(b=>b.BuildDate)` after you populate buildings with your second snippet `orderby u.UserId asending`?

Comment: I think that is a great idea.  If there is a way to do it in the LINQ I'd love to hear it.  But if not, I'll go with that way.

Comment: This is linq. I don't think you can do it in one statement. Just add the `OrderByDescending` after `ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right in using `orderby b.BuildDate descending` because that is the ordering expected in your output collection `buildings`. The ordering of the subcollection `bUsers` should be performed when passing it to `Building.Create()`:

```
List<Building> buildings = (from b in db.Buildings
                         join u in db.BuildingUsers on b.BuildingId equals u.BuildingId into bUsers
                         orderby b.BuildDate descending
                         select Building.Create(b, bUsers.OrderBy(bu => bu.UserId))).ToList();
```

Based on what you are saying above I might suggest changing `Building.Create` to accept a single user, in which case you could perform the `FirstOrDefault()` in this query:

```
List<Building> buildings = (from b in db.Buildings
                         join u in db.BuildingUsers on b.BuildingId equals u.BuildingId into bUsers
                         orderby b.BuildDate descending
                         select Building.Create(b, bUsers.OrderBy(bu => bu.UserId).FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I do need the rest of the users in my Create method though, so that advice is good otherwise.  But I was taking somebody else's LINQ and fixing it, and didn't really think about altering the Create method to do the sort in there.  That sounds great.